# Rstudio rm Error in .rs.toDataFrame names() applied to a non-vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have tried to deleted df(dataframe) with `rm`,but it is giving me an error

```
rm(df)
Error in .rs.toDataFrame(obj, objName, TRUE) : 
names() applied to a non-vector

rm(list=as.list(df))
Error in rm(list = as.list(df)) : invalid first argument

rm(list=get('df'))
Error in rm(list = get("df")) : invalid first argument
```

I know how to delete objects and columns but is there efficient way to remove complete data frame in R.

```
dupt(df)    

structure(list(Date = c("2015-08-25", "2015-08-26", "2015-08-27"
), `8552` = c(955, 2631, 2131), `8561` = c(1432, 3406, 2366)), .Names = c("Date", 
"8552", "8561"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks.

Edited

Following are some observation

```
df=df1
> df1
        Date 8552 8561
1 2015-08-25  955 1432
2 2015-08-26 2631 3406
3 2015-08-27 2131 2366
> df
        Date 8552 8561
1 2015-08-25  955 1432
2 2015-08-26 2631 3406
3 2015-08-27 2131 2366
> rm("df")
Error in .rs.toDataFrame(obj, objName, TRUE) : 
  names() applied to a non-vector   

 > df
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .External(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .External(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
<bytecode: 0x7e43270>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

**Edit2**

```
> df=1
> df
[1] 1
> rm(df)
Error in .rs.toDataFrame(obj, objName, TRUE) : 
  names() applied to a non-vector
```

i have removed df and then tried this

```
>df
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .External(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .External(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
<bytecode: 0x4eb48f0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
> rm(df)
Warning message:
In rm(df) : object 'df' not found
```

Doesnt seems to be related with data frame.Just before removing df act like a object but as soon as I `rm` it,It throws an error but rm doesnt treat df as a function also.Any reason behind this abnormal behaviour.

**FinalEdit**
As mentioned by @RHertel:

The part with .rs.toDataFrame in the beginning of the error message makes me suspect that this error is connected with the **data Viewer of RStudio**. I think it could be good to start a fresh session and/or to delete all the variables in the environment (by clicking on the broom in the "Environment" tab on the upper right in RStudio). I didn't get the same error without using RStudio, e.g., when using R's standard GUI. I have not received the same error after restarting the new fresh session.

Comment: `rm(list=ls(pattern='^df$'))` would work

Comment: @akrun :Showing same Error in .rs.toDataFrame(obj, objName, TRUE) : 
  names() applied to a non-vector

Comment: using your dput, I am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are describing is not abnormal. In `R`, `df()` is a (rarely used) function that yields the so-called F-distribution (see `?df`).

If you define a dataframe and name it `df`, then this variable name wil be used to store the dataframe, and you can see its content by typing `df`in the console. But if you type `df` in the console after (successfully) deleting the dataframe with `rm(df)`, then you obtain a description of the built-in function `df`; similar to the result that you get by typing any other function name without parameters like, e.g., `ls` instead of `ls()`.

If you use a variable name that is not occupied by a built-in function, then the result is as expected.

Here is an example:

```
> my_df <- data.frame(c(1:3))
> my_df
  c.1.3.
1      1
2      2
3      3
> rm(my_df)
> my_df
Error: object 'my_df' not found
```

Comment: @RHetrel: I agree that df is function but if you see in above mentioned activity df itself shows records and act as a data frame(dput also show the same) just before removing it.Why is it throwing an error ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error messages that you mentioned. I have defined  `df` using your `dput` output and could remove it without error messages with `rm(df)`. Maybe you can try to start a fresh R session to see if the error message occurs again. Possibly RStudio is using your `df` data somewhere else? I'm just guessing, since I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: In any case, your output `> df` yielding `function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) ...` indicates that the dataframe `df` has been deleted successfully, in spite of the error messages or warnings.

Comment: The part with `.rs.toDataFrame` in the beginning of the error message makes me suspect that this error is connected with the data Viewer of [RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionDataViewer.R). I think it could be good to start a fresh session and/or to delete all the variables in the environment (by clicking on the broom in the "Environment" tab on the upper right in RStudio). Do you get the same error without using RStudio, e.g., when using `R`'s standard GUI?